# Dashed line in plotly::add_segment

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly, line-segment

Is there a way to use the add_segments() function to create a dashed line?

I've tried using linetype, linetypes, line = list(...), dash = "dash" but nothing seems to work. Here is some sample code with a horizontal line. Right now it's just ignoring the linetype argument.

```
plot <- plot_ly() %>%
  add_segments(x = 1, xend = 10, y = 5, yend = 5, linetype = "dashed")
plot
```

I have a way around this, but I like the simplicity/readability of add_segments so it would be ideal to use it as opposed to add_lines().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`plotly::add_segment` does not have a `linetype` argument. You can set the line type like below;

```r
library(plotly)

plot_ly() %>%
  add_segments(x = 1, xend = 10, y = 5, yend = 5, line = list(dash = "dash"))
```

[image]